# Reg exp for AWS Route53 hosted zone ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Does anyone know of one?  The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_HostedZone.html) simply say

> Length Constraints: Maximum length of 32.
>
> Required: Yes

but they seem to have a regular form; e.g. only upper-case letters and numbers, starting with `Z` etc.

Comment: Since the official docs do not state one you will most likely not get a useful answer here. Do you want to add some kind of validation to a Hosted Zone ID variable / input field? Either decide that you *see* a pattern, risking it being wrong, AWS changing it, ... - or allow everything / do not validate except for the length constraint.

Comment: @luk2302 - fair point.  Yes, it's for validation (in a Terraform script).  I was thinking that there probably *is* an official pattern to them but it's just not well documented.  For example, do they always start with 'Z' (for "Zone", presumably)?

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for a quick answer also. The AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_HostedZone.html) state that the length of a hosted zone ID can be up to 32 characters at the time of typing this. I have a couple of hosted zones which are over 5 years old and they are 14 characters long so my best guess (For Now) would be `[A-Z0-9]{8,32}`.

More than happy to accept a better answer/explanation.